# Windows desktop can't connect to Server 2003 share

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003

```
Client desktops tested: Windows 7 and Windows 11
DC: Server 2008 R2 SP1
Share host: Server 2003 

Example Client IP: 10.10.20.10 / 255.255.0.0
Example DC Server 2008 IP: 10.10.10.2 / 255.255.0.0
Example Server 2003 IP: 10.10.10.10 / 255.255.0.0
```

Yes I am able to connect to share via IP from both client machines: \\10.10.10.10
Ping resolves correct IP from both client machines: ping myshare = 10.10.10.10
nbtstat -a 10.10.10.10: returns a table that looks right.
nslookup myshare: returns my DC/DNS server and myshare with correct IP

Error from File Explorer when trying to access hostname:
"Windows cannot access \myshare"
Error code: 0x80070035
"The network path was not found"

Help diagnosing or resolving connection issue! Thank you.

Comment: Did you restart the Server to ensure all services are running properly?

Comment: @John yes. Rebooted DC, share server, and clients

Comment: [Windows 11 has SMB1 support disabled by default](https://www.theregister.com/2022/04/20/smb1_uninstalled_by_default_windows_11/). Do you have it re-enabled? (Note that MS says they'll _remove SMB1_ support entirely in a future update - you may have to resort to using a different protocol you could bodge-support for, like SSH or NFS)

Comment: @Dai enabled SMB1 on both clients

Comment: Did this ever work in the past (esp. on Windows 11), or is this a new setup? (And anything in the Event Logs?)

Comment: Worked as of 10 ish days ago. Seems to break down in line with recent patching…

Comment: Were there Server 2003 updates (other than AV type updates).?

Comment: @John no updates that I’m aware of. Checking update history to be sure…

Answer (score 1):

We have exactly the same issue since the November 2022 updates.  We have installed the OOB update and still cannot access shares on a legacy Windows 2003 Server.  You can access via \server IP address\share name but not \server name\share name.  Any ideas appreciated.  We also tried changing the msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes attribute of the server to 0x4 but again this did not work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A recent Microsoft security update to our domain controllers caused this same issue for us.  After installing the 11/17 out-of-band patch on the DCs, we also had to set the kerberos encryption type on the server's AD computer object to RC4.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-fixes-windows-kerberos-auth-issues-in-emergency-update

Comment: We applied the patch. I'm looked at Default Domain Policy on the primary DC and all encryption types are checked in Default Domain Policy > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: Configure encryption types.

Comment: Still no luck though.. Should I be making the RC4 change elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for that path TexasViking!  Kvothe1911, you missed an S at the end of your URL.  Please fix.  Also, this doesn't solve the problem.  Even with this applied on every domain machine, not a single Win10 machine can access the UNC of any Server 2003 machine.  My only fix was to remove KB5021249 from AD.  Putting me back to October 2022 CU